# TensorFlow object detection fails on Xamarin Android with a reshape issue

Tags: android, tensorflow, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am following this blog post and GitHub almost exactly:

[Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-apps-tensorflow/)

[Github](https://github.com/jimbobbennett/blog-samples/tree/master/UsingTensorFlowAndAzureInAndroid)

But when I run, take a picture and call this line:

```
var outputs = new float[tfLabels.Count];
tfInterface.Feed("Placeholder", floatValues, 1, 227, 227, 3);
tfInterface.Run(new[] { "loss" });
tfInterface.Fetch("loss", outputs);
```

The app actually crashes and generates the error below on the .Run line.

I get this error in the output window (and the app crashes):

> 04-04 17:39:12.575 E/TensorFlowInferenceInterface( 8017): Failed to
>   run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[Placeholder], outputs:[loss]
>   Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input to reshape is a tensor with
>   97556 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 90944
>   [[Node: block0_0_reshape0 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](block0_0_concat,
>   block0_0_reshape0/shape)]]

According to the posts I am reading from the searching I am doing on this error, I sort of understand this is due to the image not fitting the expected size exactly but in the example I am following, this is resized to fit 227x227 everytime and converted to float like in these lines:

```
var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 227, 227, false).Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, false);

var floatValues = new float[227 * 227 * 3];
var intValues = new int[227 * 227];

resizedBitmap.GetPixels(intValues, 0, 227, 0, 0, 227, 227);

for(int i = 0; i < intValues.Length; i++)
{
     var val = intValues[i];
     floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((val & 0xFF) - 104);
     floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - 117);
     floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - 123);
}
```

So, I don't understand what is causing this or how to fix it. Please help!

**UPDATE:** I found out the issue is with my model or my labels. I found this out by simply swapping in the model and label file from the sample/github above while leaving all my code the same. When I did this, I no longer get the error. HOWEVER, this still doesn't tell me much. The error is not very explanatory to point me in a direction of what could be wrong with my model. I assume it is the model because the labels file is simply just a text file with labels on each line. I used Custom Vision Service on Azure to create my model. It trained fine and tests just fine on the web portal. I then exported it as TensorFlow. So, I am not sure what I could have done wrong or how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you rename the created txt file from retraining and paste it in the assets directory?

Comment: @Leon Lu it is in my assets directory, along with the model as well. They are marked as Android Resource but set to never copy to output directory. Also, I did not rename those files. Should I have? I verified that I am able to read the labels from assets into a string array and I also have no errors loading the model from assets. Thanks!

Comment: See my update in the original post. Seems to be an issue with the model I guess?

Comment: This question is about an image classification model, not object detection. Suggest changing the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After no answers here and several days of searching and trial and error, I have found the issue. In general, I guess this reshape error I was getting you can get if you are feeding the model with an image size other that it is expecting or setup to receive.

The issue is that, everything I have read says that typically you must feed the model with a 227 x 227 x 3 image. Then, I started noticing that size varies on some posts. Some people say 225 x 225 x 3, others say 250 x 250 x 3 and so on. I had tried those sizes as well with no luck.

As you can see in my edit in the question, I did have a clue. When using somebody else's pretrained model, my code works fine. However, when I use my custom model which I created on the Microsoft Azure [CustomVision.ai](https://customvision.ai) site, I was getting this error.

So, I decided I would try to inspect the models to see what was different. I followed this post: [Inspect a pre trained model](https://medium.com/@daj/how-to-inspect-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-5fd2ee79ced0)

When I inspected the model that works using TensorBoard, I see that the input is 227 x 227 x 3 which is what I expected. However, when I viewed my model, I noticed that it was 224 x 224 x 3! I changed my code to resize the image to that size and it works! Problem went away.

So, to summarize, for some reason Microsoft Custom Vision service model generated a model to expect an image size of 224 x 224 x 3. I didn't see any documentation or setting for this. I also don't know if that number will change with each model. If you get a similar shape error, the first place I would check is the size of the image you are feeding your model and what it expects as an input. The good news is you can check your model, even if pre-trained, using TensorBoard and the post I linked above. Look at the input section, it should look something like this: [image: Model Inspection size input]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The reason it was not documented is that you can load the model and check the expected input size on the fly in your code. That actually prevents you running into troubles, if you try to use another model from CustomVision or somewhere else.

You can get an idea about how it works in this sample code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-android-customvision-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/demo/tensorflow/org/customvision_sample/MSCognitiveServicesClassifier.java